# Event Id not retrievable for SentEvent

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

While making curl request to SentEvent api endpoint I get Id as non retrievable property. Can somebody tell why is it ? How do I uniquely identify a sent event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SendID, ListID, BatchID, and SubscriberID can be used as a composite key to uniquely identify an event.

Comment: Thanks @Mac. I used SendID and SubscriberID as composite Key. It worked :)